# Correlation coefficient between normal and half-normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

If X~N(0,1) then let Y=|X|. Y is said to have half-normal distribution.
I know that E(X)=0. Therefore to find Cov(X,Y), I need to find E(XY)=E(X|X|).
Also how do I find variance of Y?
I know how to find the distribution of Y. And then I can calculate the mean and variance of Y but I was hoping for a shorter way. Also I don't know how to find E(XY)

Comment: I can find expectation of Y and variance of y by the usual method(integrating). But i was hoping for something simpler so that i dont have to calculate E(Y) and Var(Y) (because we already know E(X) and V(X) and Y=|X|.
Also I don't know how to find E(X|X|)

Comment: How about computing similar integrals for X|X|? Just treat the positive and negative ranges of X separately, so that you either get X^2 or -X^2 depending on the sign.

Comment: Ohh, so the answer is 0 right?